# Yii2 advanced template, migrations isn't working

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

It's my first try of using 'advanced template', when I try to make a standart migrations (yii migrate) with user table console shows me next:

> Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting
>   unknown property: yii\console\Request::baseUrl'

I have the empty baseUrl => '' in console/config/main.php I have done it via guide and nobody told about that param.
How can I solve that issue?

p.s 'baseUrl' => 'http://mysite/' isn't working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted that parametr at all. It works.